# How to add new line characters in a json file in unix

Tags: json, unix, hive

I have some json files where there is no new line character (\n) in the files. So when I am trying to load the files in HIVE table, some of the data is being ignored . How can I insert new line character in the json file **after each JSON object representing a row in the table**?

Comment: Don't understand the question, can you give an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON starts always with the same attribute, then you can use it as a signature for determining new JSON object start and replace each occurrence with `\n<signature>`

For example `{"id":"12","name":"Nick"}{"id":"13","name"="Bob"}`

In this case the start signature is `{"id":`, it should be replaced with `\n{"id":`

For example, using perl:

```
echo '{"id":"12","name":"Nick"}{"id":"13","name"="Bob"}' | perl -pe 's/(\{\"id\":)/\n$1/g'
```

Output:

```
{"id":"12","name":"Nick"}
{"id":"13","name"="Bob"}
```

It generates one extra `\n` at the beginning, skip it when loading or using `tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Download `jq` and use the minimal filter:

```
jq . inputfile
```